# Form values into an array for emails

Tags: php

I have a php script that sends an email to a specified email address:

```
$headers = array(
  'From: emailhidden',
  'Content-Type: text/html'
); 

$body = array(
  '<br><br><br>',
  '<h3>Success!</h3><br>',
  '<p>Your sign up for My Panda was Successful! you may now sign in using the    information provided below.</p>', 
  '<p><b>Login URL:</b> <a href="http://www.green-panda.com/my-panda.html">http://www.green-panda.com/my-panda.html</a></p>', 
  '<p><b>Username:</b> echo "$_POST[unique_id]";</p>',
  '<p><b>Username:</b>". $POST['unique_id']."</p>',
  '<p><b>Password:</b> echo "$_POST[passphrase]";</p>',
  '<p>If you ever have any problems with My Panda or have questions, please contact us at: moevans@green-panda.com'
);

mail('emailhidden', 'My Panda Registration', implode("\r\n", $body), implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

The problem lays right here: `<p><b>Username:</b> echo "$_POST[unique_id]";</p>',` and the same with the pass phrase. They display exactly like that and not like what was entered on the form. How do I get them to display what was posted on the form previous to the script? the input field names are same as the post values in the script. Thank you!

Comment: Check your quoting. 'text' . $var . 'Text';  or "text $var text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No offense intended, but your code is riddled with bugs and syntax errors.

First of all, you're using single quotes, so PHP isn't interpreting the value of your variables.

Secondly, you're calling echo inside a string literal.

Third, you are missing quotes on a lot of your POST array indexes.

Fourth, you are missing underscores for some of your $_POST variables.

Fifth, you are displaying username twice in a row, is that intended?

This should help:

```
  '<p><b>Username:</b>' .$_POST['unique_id'].'</p>',
  '<p><b>Username:</b>' .$_POST['unique_id'].'</p>', //why twice?
  '<p><b>Password:</b>' .$_POST['passphrase'].';</p>',
```

You should know: if you declare a string with single quotes, PHP will not interpret any of the variables inside.  Try this and you'll see what I mean:

```
    $foo = "Bar";
    echo '$foo';
    echo "$foo";
```

Since you are using single quotes, I added concatenation above to make the code work.  You could have accomplished the same thing by using single quotes inside your tags, and enclosing the string in double quotes.  Then you could just run the variables in line, like this:

```
    "<p><b>Username:</b>$_POST['unique_id']</p>",
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the double quotes there.

```
'<p><b>Username:</b>". $POST['unique_id']."</p>',
                    ^                     ^
```

Use single quotes instead and change `$POST` to `$_POST`:

```
'<p><b>Username:</b>' . $_POST['unique_id'] . '</p>',
```

Answer (score 0):

It's treating them like strings and therefore rendering them as written. Concatenate your variable in and your problem should be solved.

```
'<p><b>Username:</b> echo "'.$_POST[unique_id].'";</p>',
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax problem. use correct syntax of `$_POST` (with underline) and also concat strings and variables by dot with same quote

```
'<p><b>Username:</b>' . $_POST[unique_id]. '</p>'
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured that was the problem, just didn't know how to fix it. Thanks again.